# Spivak Calculus - Chapter 1 Question 4.6

Tags: calculus, analysis, proof-explanation

In Spivak's Calculus, Chapter 1 Question 4.6:

> Find all the numbers $x$ for which $x^2+x+1>2$

The chapter focuses on using the following properties of numbers to prove solutions are correct:

[image]
[image]

Based on those properties, I am able to perform the following algebra:

$
\begin{align}
x^2 + x + 1 &> 2 & \text{Given}\\
x (x + 1) + 1 &> 2 & \text{P9}\\
x (x+1) &> 1 & \text{P3 P2 and Addition}
\end{align}
$

And from there, I can note that:

$
\begin{align}
x &\neq (x+1)^{-1}\\ 
x^{-1} &\neq (x+1)\\ 
\end{align}
$

By P6, because $x (x+1) > 1$ and $x (x+1) \neq 1$.

However, in his book Spivak is able to find the following:

$
\begin{align}
x &> \frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \text{ or}\\
x &< \frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}
\end{align}
$

How does he come to that conclusion using only the properties listed above?

Comment: $x^2+x+1>2\iff x^2+x-1>0\iff (x-\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2})(x-\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}>0$ and a product of two non-zero reals is positive if and only if they have the same sign.

Comment: To be more specific, either prove the quadratic formula (which is in one of the exercises) or explicitly complete the square in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete the Square

$
\begin{align}
x^2+x+1&>2 & \text{Given}\\
x^2+x+1+0&>2+0 & \text{By Addition}\\
x^2+x+1+0&>2 & \text{By P2}\\
x^2+x+0+1&>2 & \text{By P4}\\
x^2+x+\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^2+(-1)\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^2+1 &>2 & \text{By P3}\\
\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)+(-1)\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^2+1 &>2 & \text{By P9}\\
\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)+ (-1)\left( \frac{1}{4} \right) + 1 &> 2 & \text{By Multiplication}\\
\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right) &> \left( \frac{5}{4} \right) & \text{By Addition, P3, and P2}\\
\end{align}
$

Spivak doesn't formally define exponents in Chapter 1, so it's a little difficult to finish the proof using only the properties listed in the chapter. But it is at least clear how to get to Spivak's result from there.