# Q: Spivak Calculus - Chapter 1 - Question 4.7

Tags: calculus, analysis, proof-explanation

I'm currently working through Chapter 1 of Spivak Calculus. I'm trying to solve the inequalities on problem 4 the "proper" way but I am having trouble on exercise 4 - (vii).

**Problem**

> Find all the numbers $x$ for which $x^2 - x + 10 > 16$

**Relevant Information**

The chapter introduces and uses the following properties to solve

[Properties of Numbers P1-P9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87jBv.png)

Additionally, Spivak introduces properties regarding inequalities

[Inequalities, P10-P12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK1b5.png)

The final piece of relevant information is the assertions given here:

[Assertion of ab > 0 if a < 0 and b < 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJCTN.png)

**My attempt**

$
\begin{align}
x^2 - x + 10 &> 16 & \text{Given}\\
x^2 - x - 6 &> 0 & \text{P3}\\
(x-3)(x+2) &> 0 & \text{P9}\\
& \text{...}\\
\end{align}
$

**Question**

> How to solve from here?
>
> More specifically, how to solve using the properties and assertions that Spivak has introduced. Is my attempt from $(x-3)(x+2) > 0$ onwards (shown below) the appropriate way to use these foundations?
>
> If so, how is it completed?

**My attempt continued**

The form is of $ab > 0$ this leads me to believe that I would use both *P12 - Closure under multiplication* and the assertion Spivak shows: $(-a)(-b) > 0$ to consider the following

$
\begin{align}
\text{1.} && (x-3)(x+2) \text{ is in P when} && (x-3) \text{ and } (x + 2) \text{ are both in P}\\
\text{ - OR - }\\
\text{2.} && (x-3)(x+2) \text{ is in P when} && -(x-3) \text{ and } -(x + 2) \text{ are both in P}\\
\end{align}
$

Starting with 1.

$
\begin{align}
\text{1.} && (x-3)(x+2) \text{ is in P when} && (x-3) \text{ and } (x + 2) \text{ are both in P}\\
\end{align}
$

$
\begin{align}
x - 3 &> 0 & \text{definition of P} && x+2 &> 0 && \text{definition of P} \\
x &> 3 & \text{P3} && x &> -2 && \text{P3}\\
\end{align}
$

Now with 2.

$
\begin{align}
\text{2.} && (x-3)(x+2) \text{ is in P when} && -(x-3) \text{ and } -(x + 2) \text{ are both in P}\\
\end{align}
$

$
\begin{align}
-(x - 3) &> 0 & \text{definition of P} && -(x+2) &> 0 && \text{definition of P} \\
3 &> x & \text{P3} && -2 &> x && \text{P3}\\
\end{align}
$

Condensing 1. and 2.

$
\begin{align}
x &> 3 & \text{and} && x &> -2\\
\text{- OR -}\\
3 &> x & \text{and} && -2 &> x\\
\end{align}
$

This doesn't make sense to me, how is the answer $x > 3$ and $x < -2$

**Edit:**

I see it now.

First, it's $x > 3$ **or** $x < -2$ which is obvious because $ab > 0$ OR $(-a)(-b) < 0$ which was introduced.

Second, I see why in case 1, it's $x > 3$ because $x > 3$ and $x > -2$ can be simplified to $x > 3$. Same logic to simplify case 2 and get final result.

Comment: Instead of using the "P" and "Pn" notations with no explanation, you would be much more likely to get an answer if you explained what you meant in terms understandable by someone who has never seen this book.

Comment: thank you for the feedback! I've used @StudentsTea awesome answer on a similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1878298/spivak-calculus-chapter-1-question-4-6) as a template for reformatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$x>3 \quad \text{and} \quad  x>-2 \iff x>3$$ while
$$
x<3 \quad \text{and} \quad  x<-2 \iff x<-2
$$
Thus the solution is $x>3$ or $x<-2$.

Comment: thank for your answer, it took me a while to just take a step and think about the ands/ors to see it clearly.